# Apps does not show up in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

**Hi All,
I have created an iPhone Application and have uploaded it in the Appstore. But when I search the app in iPad, it shows up in the search results, but does not open up the Application related information in the screen. It does not show up the screen to install the app in iPad.
It works fine in iPhone. But not in iPad.
Please help me....!!!!!**

Answer (score 1):

Check this post: [How can I restrict my app for iPhone's only, excluding iPod touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014664/how-can-i-restrict-my-app-for-iphones-only-excluding-ipod-touch)

It may happen due some restrictions you put in your project, for example "telephony" device capability will restrict the app from running on iPad and the application will not be even listed in the iPad app store.