# Make a universal application, but do not allow installation on iPod Touch

Tags: ios

I am making a universal application, but I don't want the user to install it on iPod Touch. Is this possible? I mean, for a universal application, supporting iPhone and iPad is a must, not ipod.. right??

Also, haw can i achieve the same, i.e stop user from installing application on iPod Touch.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want it on the iPod? Usually you'd require specific hardware features (like telephony) but that's a no go if you are supporting the iPad.

Comment: it is the client's requirement.. i need telephony too, but it will work on iPhone only, for iPad, i am connecting it to skype in that case..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be particularly hard. You have the `UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()` which can be checked against either `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` or `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone` if it reports back the latter you can do further checks against hardware features to decide whether it's an iPod or iPhone.

It seems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094928/ios-detecting-whether-or-not-device-support-phone-calls) that the most popular choice is to use the `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` `canOpenURL` -method and see if it reports YES when sending a `@"tel://..."`-type URL.

Not sure what Apple's policies are on this though...

Edit: As jrturton mentions this doesn't cover the not-install bit of the question. A quick search through stack comes up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014664/how-can-i-restrict-my-app-for-iphones-only-excluding-ipod-touch) though. It suggest using the telephony-key, unfortunately this won't hack it with iPad. Perhaps the GPS-flag might cut it?

Edit2: I came across [this very useful list](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix). According to the information compiled there
**it seems the best flag to use is `magnetometer` it is supported by all iPads sans the very first one and by no iPods...**

Comment: That won't prevent the app being _installed_, though.

Comment: True, a quick dig through Stack seems to suggest UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities can be used to take care of this. I'll make a quick note in my answer about this as well...