# Exclude iPod when submitting an app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect, ipod-touch

When I submit an application to iTunes Connect, how do I set the "Compatibility" to exclude iPod touch?

Within Xcode, my application deployment settings have a "target device family" of "iPhone/iPad", but iTunes Connect seems to include iPod touch wherever iPhone is allowed and as a result the iTunes listing for the application states: "Compatibility: Requires iOS 5.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad and iPod touch. This app is optimised for iPhone 5".

The application does run on iPod touch, but is heavily dependent on 3G and as such we would simply prefer that the iPod touch not be included in the listing.

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014664/how-can-i-restrict-my-app-for-iphones-only-excluding-ipod-touch

Comment: @iMemon; you are absolutely correct, however I fear that though the answer provided in that question will prevent installation to such devices it does not state whether it will actually change the "compatibility" text on the iTunes listing. Do you know if this is the case? I have a situation where because of that listing a user specifically bought an iPod touch but the functionality was severely limited by the lack of 3G connectivity and that resulted in complaints.

Comment: I am not completely sure about the compatibility issue. But i guess you don't have to fear about it. Just checked Whatsapp App, it is not appearing in search on iPad and iPod as expected. It is only available for iPhone.

Comment: @iMemon: problem is, I do want it available on the iPad, just not the iPod.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you want the app compatible for iPhones & iPads only but not iPod, I guess you have to set UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities entry (a dictionary) in info.plist file AND the **magnetometer** key with a value of **YES**, meaning, only devices that support **magnetometer** can use the app.

I have checked that **magnetometer** is supported by iPhones & iPads only not by iPods. Take a look at [Device Compatibility - Apple Documnetation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) for your confirmation.

I have not tested this, but it should work as stated in the documentation:

> The value of the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key is either an array or a dictionary that contains additional keys identifying features your app requires (or specifically prohibits). **If you specify the value of the key using an array, the presence of a key indicates that the feature is required; the absence of a key indicates that the feature is not required and that the app can run without it.** If you specify a dictionary instead, each key in the dictionary must have a Boolean value that indicates whether the feature is required or prohibited. A value of true indicates the feature is required and a value of false indicates that the feature must not be present on the device. If a given capability is optional for your app, do not include the corresponding key in the dictionary.
>
> Table 1-1 lists the keys that you can include in the array or dictionary for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key. You should include keys only for the features that your app absolutely requires. If your app can run without a specific feature, do not include the corresponding key.

Good Luck :)

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Also you can use the gps key